# creating a object in a method in python: invalid syntax

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a little program to create and administrate accounts with a bank.
The code is  written in German, I wrote the translation in the comments. Every time I'm
trying to compile the program the compiler says 'invalid syntax', but doesn't highlight it.
I can't find the problem, but it has to be located in the method `kontoEroeffnen()` I would be very grateful for some help.

```
import sys

# makes an account with bank


class Konto :
    def __init__( self , laufzeit , ID , password , zinssatz):
        self.ID = ID#the ID of the account
        self.laufzeit = laufzeit#runtime of the account
        self.password = password
        self.zinssatz = zinssatz#interest rate
        self.kontostaende = list(range(laufzeit + 1)#array with the months
    def authentifizierung(self):                        #authentication of the user
        print("Geben Sie Ihre Konto ID ein")#input of the account-ID
        idl = int(sys.stdin.readline().rstrip())
        print("Geben Sie ihr Passwort ein")#input of the password
        passwort = int(sys.stdin.readline().rstrip())
        if idl == self.id :
            if passwort == self.password :
                return True

            else:
                print("Falsches Passwort")#output:wrong password
                return False
        else:
            print("Erneut versuchen")#output:retry
            return False
    def einzahlen(self) :#pay into the bank
        if authentifizierung() :
            print("Wenn es Ihre Ersteinzahlung ist geben Sie e ein")#output:if this is your first pay, input 'e'
            print("Sonst geben Sie den Monat der Laufzeit ihres Kontos ein")#output:else:input the month of the runtime of your account
            eingabe = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
            if eingabe == 'e' :
                print("Geben Sie den Betrag Ihrer Einzahlung ein")#output:you have to input the sum
                self.kontostaende[0] = int(sys.stdin.readline().rstrip())
                #Hier muss noch der Verweis zur Startsequenz hin....    //here I want a jump to the startsequency(not important now...)
            else:
                index = int(eingabe)
                if (index > 0 ) and (index < len(self.kontostaende)):
                    print("Geben Sie den Betrag Ihrer Einzahlung ein")
                    self.kontostaende[index] = int(sys.stdin.readline().rstrip())
                    # Hier muss wieder zur Startsequenz... 
        else :
            einzahlen()

    def kontosteandeVomErstenTagBerechnen(self):#calculate the account balances
        for i in self.kontostaende :
            self.kontostaende[i] = self.kontostaende[0]* pow((1 + self.zinssatz) , (i/self.laufzeit))
    def kontostaendeVomTagDerEinzahlungBerechnen(self , index):
        monate = list(range(laufzeit))          #macht eine Liste der zu veraendernden elementen  //makes a list of the elements who should be changed
        for i in range (index):                 # |
            del monate[0]                       #-|
        for i in monate :
            self.kontostaende[i + index] = self.kontostaende[index] * pow((1 + self.zinssatz) , ( i / (self.laufzeit - index)))

def kontoEröffnen ():#create a new account

    print("Geben Sie die gewuenschte ID Ihres Kontos ein")#input the ID of your account
    ID = int(sys.stdin.readline().rstrip())
    print("Geben Sie das Passwort, das Sie benutzen wollen ein, achten sie darauf es niemandem zu verraten")#input the password of your account
    password = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
    print("Geben Sie die Laufzeit des Vertrags ein")#input the runtime of your account
    laufzeit = int(sys.stdin.readline().rstrip())
    print("Geben Sie den Zinssatz Ihres Vertrags ein, in Dezimalschreibweise.")#input the interest rate in decimal
    zinssatz = float(sys.stdin.readline().rstrip())
    konto = Konto(laufzeit , ID , password , zinssatz)                  
    return konto
    #noch nicht fertig // not finished because doesn't work
def startsequenz (): #start sequency....doesn't matter for this.
    print (''' Geben Sie ein ob sie ein Konto haben oder eröffnen wollen!
geben Sie, wenn Sie ein Konto haben, k ein, Sie e ein.''')
    if sys.stdin.read(1) == e :
        kontoEröffnen()
    #nicht fertig
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you not using `raw_input()` or `input()` (Python 2 and 3 respectively), but are reading directly from `sys.stdin`?

Comment: And last but not least, what is the **full** error message you get?

Comment: It will tell you what line the syntax error is on. Look at that line and the one above it (it could be you forgot to close a parenthesis or something).

Comment: @kindall: If this is Python 2 then the name of the function is a syntax error; only ASCII characters allowed..

Comment: try remove the "**ö**" from **kontoEröffnen**

Comment: @Jerry_Y: In Python 3, using non-ASCII letter characters in identifiers is perfectly legal.

Comment: ohhhh there are so many fails..... it's very embrassing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis in your `Konto.__init__` method:

```
self.kontostaende = list(range(laufzeit + 1)#array with the months
#             ------------------------------^ missing
```

Add the parenthesis there at the end:

```
self.kontostaende = list(range(laufzeit + 1))
```

Comment: OK some of my fails are very embressing... like the 'ö', but this char shouldn't make a error... in a book I've read the author used everytime mutated vocals.

   /////// The missing closing paranthisis is very embrassing.

     ////////I'm using python 3.3 (is anyone using python 2 anymore?)

      /////// ....And the error was the missing closing paranthesis (hitting my head on the desk)      ///////  sorry, this error I should be able to find.

   ////////  Thanks to you all and for your labour.\\\\\\\\

          //have I got to close the thread?like in ubuntuusers?

Comment: I've accepted it ofcourse....could you explane input()?...I'm  a  greenhorn.

Comment: @user3266704: the [`input()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) just takes user input; the user is given a prompt, and input is taken until the user hits the enter key.